# Как узнать, на чем написан сайт

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Как понять, на каком языке написан Web-сайт/Web-страница? Есть специальные ПО или расширения для браузере, что-бы понять, на каком языке написан Web-сайт ?

Comment: только по косвенным признакам

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?hl=ru

Comment: https://builtwith.com/

Comment: https://itrack.ru/whatcms

Comment: А вот, как мне узнать через Dev Tools в Chrome-браузере, где расположен файл Web-страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Вот расширение :

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?hl=ru

С ним можно узнать на чем написан сайт. Хорошей разработки:)
UPD: вот еще одно:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/similartech-prospecting/jiabgmelnfhgjkfdaoiccfcbaedjfcnm?hl=ru

Советую использовать два этих расширения, так как они дополняют друг-друга.
Если интересно:https://lifehacker.ru/wappalyzer/